# Can I use Paired Proportions Test

Tags: proportion

If I wish to see if a crime rate during period x is the same (statistically) as period y, could I use a paired proportions test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have the sample sizes associated with each percentage estimate.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment. Also, what does it mean to "have the sample sizes associated with each percentage estimate"?

Comment: A percentage is any portion or share in relation to a whole; as such, to calculate a percentage, one needs to know the size of the whole, $n$, often called the "sample size", and one needs to know the number within that whole meeting the desired criteria, $k$.  The proportion is calculate by dividing the number meeting that criteria with the size of the entire whole, $p=k/n$.